# PGconn Error on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I got this error message after I cloned a code to my c9.io. can anyone explain the error below to me what to do please?

[image]

Comment: did u start postgree ? also ist in `c9.io` ?

Comment: I tryed to run the server and I got the above message. PG gem is already installed if that is what  you are asking?

Comment: Have you even tried to search for the similar issues, i found tons of similar questions. please just copy the error and google

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

`sudo service postgresql start` ?

Use this link as a guide if you get stuck: https://community.c9.io/t/setting-up-postgresql/1573